# How to sync app data across multiple i-devices?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS app development and am interested in developing an app that needs to utilize existing technologies to sync app specific data across multiple i-devices (iPhone, iPad, Touch, etc.). As an example, the app can be installed on multiple devices. On one device, the user will initially create an account. Then in subsequent logins, the user may create a task list, and each task item may possibly include a captured photo image. On the user's second i-device, as he logs in, he would be able to see and access the list and images (locally). Can someone explain to me what technologies I can leverage on to implement such an app?

Specifically:

How do I set up and manage the user accounts? Do I Need a dedicated server and sql database set up for my entire user base? And what programming/scripting languages do I need to learn?

How about the mechanism of pushing and pulling app data from one device to another? Do I need some kind of cloud technologies (SaaS?) to handle the storage and transferring of the data?

Any specific open source or commercial products I can leverage on?

Thanks in advance.

Kenny

Comment: If these are all Apple devices, you should take a hard look at iCloud and make your life simple. How much work do you really want to do? This is what iCloud was designed for!

Comment: The app will initially be developed for iOS, but eventually be ported to Android as well so iCloud will not be a feasible option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have not have had a situation like this, but here is what I would recommend.

You will need to have a server set up with database software. 
You will need to write an api for yourself based on HTTP POST (REST) or maybe you could write a SOAP service.

I would **HIGHLY** recommend purchasing an **SSL cert**. for your server that way you can send the username and password in your request and it will be encrypted automatically.

For the api, you have a whole selection of languages and databases at your disposal. I am personally biased towards asp net with an MSSQL server.

with your api you will need to write methods to authenticate the user, and then save and send your data.

In your app you will simply send web requests to the server (ASIHttpRequest maybe?) and you can receive JSON responses back, which you can then deserialize into workable objects and vice versa.

if you do use asp net, you can use the newtonsoft JSON library to convert your objects for sending and convert received objects.

I dont remember the name, but there also is a JSON library for obj-c that is usable on iPhone.

Comment: I already have an existing web-hosting account which is Linux based that I want to leverage on so asp is not an option. In this case, what would be your recommendation? php and mysql?

Comment: well, asp is an option (mono project) but mssql is not. In that case php and mysql are your best bet. I have no experience in php, but I know that if you wanted to go the asp route, it will work with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL server and host a database of logins and passwords.
Then, from each device, create a connection to the server, and download the login information for the account. 
Also, not to be rude but: Google it.

Comment: I would like to google also but it is difficult to pin down the proper keywords to search without knowing what specific technologies/programming languages I need for such implementation.

Comment: search how to create a user-password login combination in iphone os, using a server